# Use elasticsearch from matlab code

Tags: matlab, elasticsearch, bigdata

I would like to use elasticsearch from MATLAB to do this:

1-   Insert an alphanumeric string as a request in the search engine

2-   Search in a large database, NOSQL.

Comment: What solutions did you try out?

Comment: I wanted to access to elasticsearch core from matlab, I did't know how to do. If you can tell me the first steps to solve the problem.

Comment: I think I can connect through JSON